# Copy rows from 2 tables from one database to 1 table in other database but same server in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys so i have this code but when i run it the new database is empty i really dont know why there is no error log, here is my code:

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_nombre="****";
$db_nombre2="*****";
$db_usuario="****";
$db_password="*****";
ini_set('memory_limit','500M');

$conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_password,$db_nombre);
$conexion2=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_password,$db_nombre2);

$data = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT v.id, v.userid,v.dueDate, v.status, c.firstname, c.lastname, c.phonenumber FROM tblinvoices v, tblclients c WHERE v.dueDate > '2017-12-10'");
$values = Array();


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {

$row[id] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$row['id']);
$row[userid] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$row['userid']);
$row[duedate] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$row['duedate']);
$row[status] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$row['status']);
$row[firstname] =     mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$row['lastname']);
$row[lastname] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$row['lastname']);
$row[phonenumber] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$row['phonenumber']);

$values[]='("$row[id]","$row[userid]""$row[duedate]","$row[status]","$row[firstname]","$row[lastname]","$row[phonenumber]")';
}


mysqli_query($conexion2,'INSERT INTO cobranzaSemanal (idInVoice,idUser,dueDate,status,firstName,lastName,phoneNumber) VALUES '.implode(',',$values)."");

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to swap your quotes in your `$value[] = ....`. You need the double on the outside and single around the values, as php won’t parse inside single quotes

Comment: You could also do your own debugging using `mysqli_error($conexion2);`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the username and password are the same for both databases you should be able to combine both queries like this

```
$sql="insert into `$db_nombre2`.`cobranzaSemanal` ( `idInVoice`, `idUser`, `dueDate`, `status`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `phoneNumber` )
    (
        select v.`id`, v.`userid`, v.`duedate`, v.`status`, c.`firstname`, c.`lastname`, c.`phonenumber`
        from `$db_nombre`.`tblinvoices` v, `tblclients` c 
        where v.`duedate` > '2017-12-10'
    )";
```